# Is there anyway we can bypass [unique=true] while doing impex import? It says one unique key is must for an itemtype

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

Is there anyway we can bypass [unique=true] while doing impex import? It says one unique key is must for an itemtype.

I need to store data in an itemtype like below but validating impex itself is throwing error and it says unique=true should be present for atleast one attribute. Please suggest how to mitigate this issue. Appreciate any help.

```
Impex : INSERT SolrSearchTopResults;keyword;searchDate;lang(isocode);resultCount;fromBatch

;shovels;01-02-2016 9:54:30;en;30;true 
;shovels;01-02-2016 9:54:32;en;32;true 
;shovels;01-02-2016 9:54:45;en;32;true
```

Itemtype:

```
<itemtype code="SolrSearchTopResults" extends="GenericItem" autocreate="true" generate="true" >
<deployment table="SolrSearchTopResults" typecode="12398" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impex import 'insert' header doesn't need a unique field, only 'insert_update', 'update' and 'delete' require a unique field.

If you want to by pass this limitation for update / delete you could use '[batch=true]'.

Comment: Thanks A lot Mr.Benoit

Comment: You are welcome, plead mark the question as solved if it's the case